# Proving discontinuity of a map between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$, at a single point

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, continuity

I am trying to show that, no matter what $c \in \mathbb{R}$ we take in the below, $f$ is not continuous at $0$:
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{x_1^2-x_2^2}{x_1^2+x_2^2} & \text { if } x \neq 0 \\
c & \text { if } x=0
\end{array}\right.
$$

Is my attempt correct?

Consider first some arbitrary $c\in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{-1, 1\}$.  Set $\epsilon:= \min\{|c-1|, |c+1|\}$. Consider some arbitrary $\delta>0$. Choose $x:= (x_1, x_2)$ such that $d(x, 0)=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}<\delta$.  Now, note that: $|f(0)-f(x)|=|c-\frac{x_1^2-x_2^2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}|=|\frac{(x_1^2+x_2^2)c-x_1^2+x_2^2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}|=|\frac{x_1^2c+x_2^2c+x_2^2-x_1^2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}|=|\frac{x_1^2(c-1)+x_2^2(c+1)}{x_1^2+x_2^2}|\geq\frac{x_1^2|(c-1)|+x_2^2|(c+1)|}{|x_1^2+x_2^2|} > \frac{(x_1^2+x_2^2)\min\{|c-1|,  |c+1|\}}{|x_1^2+x_2^2|}=$ $\min \{|c-1|, |c+1|\}$.

Next, consider $c=1$. Set $\epsilon:=1$. Consider some arbitrary $\delta>0$. Choose $x:= (x_1, x_2)$ such that $x_1=0$, and $x_2=\sqrt\frac{\delta}{2}$. Then $d(x, 0)<\delta$, but $|f(0)-f(x)|=|c-\frac{x_1^2-x_2^2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}|=|\frac{2x_2^2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}|={2}>1.$

Finally, consider $c=-1$. Set $\epsilon:=1$. Consider some arbitrary $\delta>0$. Choose $x:= (x_1, x_2)$ such that $x_2=0$, and $x_1=\sqrt\frac{\delta}{2}$. Then $d(x, 0)<\delta$, but $|f(0)-f(x)|=|c-\frac{x_1^2-x_2^2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}|=|\frac{2x_1^2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}|={2}>1.$

Comment: I run into a problem if $c=-1$. From your inequality I obtain then  $x_1^2>x_1^2+x_2^2$.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis is the negation of that definition not: there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ there exists $x\in X$ such that $d(x,0)<\delta$ and $d(f(x), f(0)) \geq \epsilon$?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis my $\epsilon$ in the first part of the proof is guaranteed to be greater than 0.

Comment: @Charles You're right. I didn't notice the absolute value. Your last inequality does not seem correct though...

Comment: @311411 I have updated my post.

Comment: Well it's great that you are using inequalities and the definition of continuity by hand and verifying . But another often very very useful way of showing/disproving continuity is by means of sequences . That is if you take any sequence $x_{n}$ converging to $f(x)$, then $f(x_{n})$ should converge to $f(x)$. So here take $(\frac{1}{n},\frac{a}{n})$ for any $a\in\Bbb{R}$ . Then what happens to $f(x_{n})$? . you just get $\frac{1-a^{2}}{1+a^{2}}$ which is different for different values of $a$. Thus the limit is not unique and hence cannot exist.

Comment: Would you care to justify this? - - - $$ \left| \frac{x_1^2(c-1)+x_2^2(c+1)}{x_1^2+x_2^2} \right| \geq \frac{x_1^2|(c-1)|+x_2^2|(c+1)|}{|x_1^2+x_2^2|}  $$

Comment: @311411 it follows by the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach lies in the fact that if for real numbers we have $a>b$ then we cannot deduce that $|a|>|b|$. In your case, while it's true that $x_1^2(c-1)+x_2^2(c+1) \geq (x_1^2+x_2^2)\cdot \min\{c-1,c+1\}$, you cannot take absolute values of both sides because you have no guarantee that they are both positive. As an example, for $c=-1$ the inequality gives $-2x_1^2 \geq -2(x_1^2+x_2^2)$ but when you take absolute values you get $x_1^2\geq x_1^2+x_2^2$ which is obviously not correct.

The simplest way to attack this problem is to find two paths that give rise to two different limits which will prove that the limit of $f$ at $(0,0)$ does not exist.

Comment: Does my edit address this concern?

Comment: @Charles Now $\varepsilon$ can be equal to $0$ (if $c=-1$)

Comment: Apologies. I have now provided a separate treatment of $c=-1$. Does my update work? Thank you.